# Table cell image background not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I'm using the code below in my view controller but the background image is not showing. Any idea what could be the issue?

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background.png"]];
   /* I also tried: cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background.png"]]; */
}
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: Did you check that [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-bacground.png"] is not nil? Looks to me like it should be [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background.png"]

Comment: use cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];

Comment: it's just an error when copying to stackoverflow...

Comment: I'm not sure how allocating the object could change something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting in the dark, but have you tried

```
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-bacground.png"]];
```

or perhaps you misspelled background in the image path? ;-)

Comment: Found the issue. I'm using a View in the Custom Cell view. So it was hiding the actual background. I just had to clear the View color before then it worked!

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView *theImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
[theImageView setFrame:SomeRect];
[[cell contentView] setBackgroundView:theImageView];
[theImageView release];

That will work.

Comment: Found the issue. I'm using a View in the Custom Cell view. So it was hiding the actual background. I just had to clear the View color before then it worked!

Comment: Awesome, that's a common mistake.